# Getting 400 Error while Authenticating user credentials using fetch API

Tags: reactjs, .net, asp.net-core, fetch, fetch-api

I am using asp.net core as backend and react as a front-end. I am using fetch API to authenticate user credentials.

But when I am trying to log in I am getting a 400 error. Everything is working fine on the postman.

Here is my react code:

```
 const submitLoginForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await fetch("https://localhost:44316/api/auth/login", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password,
      })
    });

    setRedirectTo(true);

  };
```

I am calling the above function on form submit.

Comment: Is the XSRF token being sent (in cookies / headers)? I see you have `credentials: include` but double check if it's really sent.

Comment: It was included because I am getting cookie from the server

Answer (score 0):

Just add the => Accept: "application/json" in headers section

```js
const submitLoginForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await fetch("https://localhost:44316/api/auth/login", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password,
      })
    });

    setRedirectTo(true);

  };
```